# How to get grid for every item wise jquery-and-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How to get grid for item wise J query-and-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater Please help me out from this,Please modify the logic here Below my code is their 
     Here I am generating one report
Thanks in advance.

```
  function DataReports2(invurl, nameofmaint) {
                var stringParameter = "{'" +
                        "fromdate':'" + $("#txtInvReportCommonFromDate").val() + "','" +
                        "todate':'" + $("#txtInvReportCommonToDate").val() + "','" +
                        "Itemname':'" + $("#dataItemId").val() +
                         "'}";

                $("#tblinvledgerreport").html("");
                var Itemcolor = "";
                var Itemcolorindex = 0;
                $("#lblfromdate").text($("#txtInvReportCommonFromDate").val())
                $("#lbltodate").text($("#txtInvReportCommonToDate").val())
                $("#lblledgerreport").text(nameofmaint);
                 $("#tblinvledgerreport").append("<thead class='gridColorHeader'>" +
                                      "<tr style='color: White;background-color: RGB(0,153,0);  font-weight: bold;height: 30px;' class='header'>" +
                                          "<th align='center'>SNO</th>" +
                                          "<th align='center'>Type</th>" +
                                          "<th align='center'>Date</th>" +
                                          "<th align='center'>Transaction Description</th>" +
                                         "<th align='center'>Reference Doc</th>" +
                                          "<th align='center' colspan='2'>Receipts</th>" +
                                         "<th align='center' colspan='2'>Issuance</th>" +

                                      "</tr>" +
                                    "<tr style='color: White; font-weight: bold;height: 30px;' class='header'>" +
                                           "<th></th>" +
                                          "<th></th>" +
                                            "<th></th>" +
                                            "<th></th>" +
                                            "<th></th>" +
                                       "<th>QTY</th>" +
                                       "<th>UNITPRICE</th>" +
                                       "<th>QTY</th>" +
                                       "<th>UNITPRICE</th>" +

                                 "</tr>" +                            
                                               "</thead>" +
                                               "<tbody>");
                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: invurl,
                    cache: false,
                    data: "{'" +
                        "fromdate':'" + $("#txtInvReportCommonFromDate").val() + "','" +
                        "todate':'" + $("#txtInvReportCommonToDate").val() + "','" +
                        "Itemname':'" + $("#dataItemId").val() +
                     "'}",

                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'JSON',

                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.d.length > 0) {
                            for (var index in data.d) {
                                $("#lblitemname").text(data.d[index].ITEM_NAME);
                                if (Itemcolorindex == index) {
                                    Itemcolor = "background-color:white";
                                    Itemcolorindex = Itemcolorindex + 2;
                                }
                                else {
                                    Itemcolor = "background-color:#EFF3FB;";
                                }


                                $("#tblinvledgerreport").append("<tr style=" + Itemcolor + ">" +
                                                     "<td>" + data.d[index].TBLID + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + data.d[index].TYPE + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + getOldDate(data.d[index].DATE) + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td align='center'>" + data.d[index].TransactionDescription + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td align='center'>" + data.d[index].ReferenceDoc + "</td>" +
                                                    "<td>" + (data.d[index].QTYReceipts == null ? '' : data.d[index].QTYReceipts) + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + (data.d[index].UNITPRICEReceipts == null ? '' : data.d[index].UNITPRICEReceipts) + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + (data.d[index].QTYISS == null ? '' : data.d[index].QTYISS) + "</td>" +
                                                    "<td>" + (data.d[index].UNITPRICEiss == null ? '' : data.d[index].UNITPRICEiss) + "</td>" +
                                                                "</tr>");                                                    
                            }
                            $("#tblinvledgerreport").append("</tbody>");

                        }
                        else {
                            $("#tblinvledgerreport").append("<tr>" +
                                         "<td align='center' style='font-weight:bold; color:Red' colspan='10'>No Records</td>" +
                                                        "</tr>");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Something went wrong. Please Contact Administrator with Details.");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: You want to build a grid out of your data?? Now what is the problem in the current code posted above,

Comment: above problem is actually if u give item name result will come but if u give didn't item name i need to display all itemnames item wise repeatedly with same design

Comment: How to Use Repeater here

Comment: there is nothing like repeater in Jquery. you need to loop in the data and construct a table.

Comment: Thank u and Please help me how to take loop here

Comment: Already your Ajax success method is doing that right? there it is looping the data and creating a table